# CSS3 Hover transition strange behavior

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

So I was playing around with transition/hover effects so that's the code.

HTML

```
  <section>
    <a href="#" title="button">CLICK!</a>
    <a href="#" title="button">CLICK!</a>
    <a href="#" title="button">CLICK!</a>
    <a href="#" title="button">CLICK!</a>
  </section>
```

LESS

```
section {
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 250px auto;
    position:  relative;
    background: #08c;

    a {
      border-radius: 51px;
      background: #e60;
      line-height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #04e;
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: tahoma;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;

      &:nth-child(1){
          position: absolute;
          top: -100px;
          left: -100px;
          -webkit-transition: left 2s ease;

          &:hover,
          &:focus{
            left: 800px;
          }
      }
      &:nth-child(2){
          position: absolute;
          top: -100px;
          right: -100px;
          -webkit-transition: top 2s ease;

          &:hover{
            top: 600px;
          }
      }
      &:nth-child(3){
          position: absolute;
          bottom: -100px;
          right: -100px;
          -webkit-transition: right 2s ease;

          &:hover{
            right: 600px;
          }
      }
      &:nth-child(4){
          position: absolute;
          bottom: -100px;
          left: -100px;
          -webkit-transition: bottom 2s ease;

          &:hover{
            bottom: 600px;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

example: http://jsbin.com/anitob/1

BUT, I stumbled upon a strange thing. When I hover over a link its starts getting to its right position applied by the hover, but at some point (always different) the effect stops and it gets back to its original position!

Have anyone seen this and know what is the problem ?

Comment: For our convenience, can you repost the code (preferably as a jsfiddle)?  It looks like there was some mangling in the copy-pasting, as it's missing characters in the tags.

Comment: nice effect by the way) http://jsbin.com/anitob/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@zeMinimalist is right.

The way to cheat around this (if you want to stay with the hover effect) is to move the image but not the element.

So basicly your image would be a dummy element laid on top of the element with the hover effect. Then when they hover over the 'image' it moves as expected and doesn't reset because the element with the hover trigger hasn't moved.

so something like this:

```
.moving_element{
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: bottom 2s ease;
} 
.static_element:hover .moving_element{
   left: 800px; 
}
```

So the user hovers over the `.static_element` but the `.moving_element` is the one that transitions.

Comment: Thank you for adding an alternative. I was thinking I probably should have done that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your hover effect is on an object that moves. So once you move your mouse at all, it'll reset itself as the browser will recognize the mouse is no longer on the element. Perhaps sometimes the browser doesn't require you move your mouse, and this is why it may seem random.

Comment: I was suspecting that, but I wanted to exclude the possibility of a local problem. Thank you :)